# How to use expect command with .run program in replace for yes command

Tags: bash, command

The [program.run](https://freefilesync.org/download/FreeFileSync_11.6_Linux.tar.gz) I'm trying to run:

- Asks 2 questions that need the answer "y"
- Asks a third question at the end which is "press any key to exit"

[image]

In addition, it doesn't have the "-y" option. Only this options:

```
FreeFileSync installation parameters:
-h, --help    Show help
--directory   Change installation directory e.g. --directory /opt/FFS
--noshortcuts  Don't create desktop shortcuts
```

And neither of these commands work:

```
yes | sudo ./program.run
yes y | sudo ./program.run
sudo sh -c 'yes y | ./program.run'
echo y | sudo ./program.run
# etc, etc
```

[image]

Since the "yes" command does not seem to work, I would like to try anything else

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6316659/8747573), say: *"a .run command is simply a set of commands that are going to be run by sh. A particular .run file might take a -y option but in general you can't count on it. If you need to automate some stuff, consider using [Expect](http://linux.die.net/man/1/expect)"*.

But I don't know how to use [Expect](http://linux.die.net/man/1/expect). Some help?

Distro: Ubuntu Mate 20.04 LTS

Bash 5.0.17(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

**Update:**

I have posted this issue on the official site and the developers [announced](https://freefilesync.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=8137) that in the next version they will add the parameter:

```
./program.run --accept-license
```

Comment: How exactly doesn't `yes` work? Can you post the code of the program you're trying to automate?

Comment: I don't have the program code. I guess it doesn't recognize my commands, because the questions keep getting when executing them. I have updated the question with the link to the program

Comment: You have only those 3 questions, or is it a (long/endless) stream of questions?

Comment: @d.c. I have published an image that answers your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `expect` that would be:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

set timeout -1
log_user 0
spawn ./FreeFileSync_11.6_Install.run
log_user 1

expect -exact "\r
Accept the FreeFileSync license terms? (Enter 's' to show them) \[y/n/s\] "
send -- "y\r"
expect -exact "y\r
Install FreeFileSync into /opt/FreeFileSync? \[Y/n\] "
send -- "Y\r"
expect -exact "https://freefilesync.org/donate\r
\r"
```

Run:

```
$ sudo ./expect-script
[sudo] password for user:

Accept the FreeFileSync license terms? (Enter 's' to show them) [y/n/s] y
Install FreeFileSync into /opt/FreeFileSync? [Y/n] Y

-> Installing to: /opt/FreeFileSync
-> New console command: freefilesync
-> Registering file extensions: *.ffs_gui, *.ffs_batch, *.ffs_real

All done!

      (\_/)
  (  =(^Y^)=
   \_(m___m)

Get the Donation Edition with bonus features and help keep FreeFileSync ad-free.
https://freefilesync.org/donate
```

Comment: yeah. I have no idea how what you just posted works, but it works. Thanks. PS: I suggest you explain a little how that script works

Comment: You need to learn [expect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect) to understand how it works.

Answer (score 0):

If I want to provide auto answers for 3 questions as follows:

y< enter >

y< enter >

< enter >

I would use something like:

```
printf "y\ny\n\n" | sudo ./program.run
```

Comment: It didn't work. But thanks for the effort in helping me

Comment: Of course, the program can get rid of any of your "precooked" answers. But what about giving it a second try - simplifying it a bit: first make `sudo su` and then, run just `printf "y\ny\n\n" | ./program.run`

Comment: already did. the same result. the questions continue to appear in an additional window

Comment: Could you download the program.run in the question link and do the tests? Thanks

Comment: Well, I am sorry - didn't recognize that it's in different window. Than you can do little about it. Can't replicate either, program is distributed only of x86 arch (and on Mac it's completely different).